# Change hostname in datastax-agent

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I've noticed when working in Opscenter that all the nodes are displayed with the result of `hostname` and their IP address.  For an ec2 host this is a little redundant since the hostnames look like `ip-10-0-0-1`.  I was hoping to override this node's name to it's ec2 instance id either in the datastax-agent or in cassandra.

Is there a way to set an explicit node name in `datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml` or some other location?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently a dev on the OpsCenter team.  We don't currently have any way to explicitly name nodes. We've talked about it recently as it would be useful to improve how we test OpsCenter, but it isn't something we've planned to implement yet.